# error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

Tags: c++, compilation-errors, debugging

I have a decent level of programming skill, or at least I thought so. I've been getting an error when compiling this Ardulno sketch. I don't really know what this error means or how to fix it. What's wrong with my code that's causing these errors. I was in the middle of making a big change to my code, so a lot of it is commented out because I haven't gotten to those parts.

code:

```
#include <LinkedList.h>

const uint8_t PinLeft = 2;
const uint8_t PinMiddle = 3;
const uint8_t PinRight = 4;
const uint8_t PinLED = 13;

enum MouseButtons {LEFT, MIDDLE, RIGHT} ;

bool leftPressed = false;
bool middlePressed = false;
bool rightPressed = false;

void sendMouseState() {
    if (leftPressed == true && middlePressed == false && rightPressed == false) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(1, 0, 0);
    } else if (leftPressed == true && middlePressed == true && rightPressed == false) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(1, 1, 0);
    } else if (leftPressed == true && middlePressed == true && rightPressed == true) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(1, 1, 1);
    } else if (leftPressed == true && middlePressed == false && rightPressed == true) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(1, 0, 1);
    } else if (leftPressed == false && middlePressed == true && rightPressed == false) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(0, 1, 0);
    } else if (leftPressed == false && middlePressed == false && rightPressed == true) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(0, 0, 1);
    } else if (leftPressed == false && middlePressed == true && rightPressed == true) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(0, 1, 1);
    } else if (leftPressed == false && middlePressed == false && rightPressed == false) {
        Mouse.set_buttons(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

void mouseButtonPress(MouseButtons theButton);
void mouseButtonPress(MouseButtons theButton) {
    if (theButton == MouseButtons::LEFT) {
        leftPressed = true;
    } else if(theButton == MouseButtons::MIDDLE) {
        middlePressed = true;
    } else if (theButton == MouseButtons::RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
}

void mouseButtonRelease(MouseButtons button);
void mouseButtonRelease(MouseButtons button) {
    if (button == LEFT) {
        leftPressed = false;
    } else if(button == MIDDLE) {
        middlePressed = false;
    } else if (button == RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
}

volatile unsigned int nextPressLeft = 0;
volatile unsigned int nextPressCenter = 0;
volatile unsigned int nextPressRight = 0;
const int timeBetween = 150; //milliseconds

enum ActionType {KB, MOU}; //keyboard or mouse

class Action {
    public:
        uint16_t keyCode;
        ActionType actionType;

        Action (uint16_t keyCode, ActionType actionType) {
            this->keyCode = keyCode;
            this->actionType = actionType;
        }

};

class ModeAction {

    public:
        LinkedList<Action> *keys = new LinkedList<Action>();

        void addAction(Action action) {
            keys->add(action);
        }

};

class ActionManager {

    private:
        uint8_t modeL = 1;
        uint8_t modeM = 1;
        uint8_t modeR = 1;

        LinkedList<ModeAction> *lActions = new LinkedList<ModeAction>();
        LinkedList<ModeAction> *mActions=new LinkedList<ModeAction>();
        LinkedList<ModeAction> *rActions=new LinkedList<ModeAction>();

        bool lActing = false, mActing = false, rActing = false;

    public:
        ActionManager() {
            //actions for left switch
            //mode 1
            lActions->add(ModeAction());
            lActions->get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(MouseButtons.LEFT, ActionType.MOU));
            //mode 2
            lActions->add(ModeAction());
            lActions->get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(KEY_F11, ActionType.KB));
            //mode 3
            lActions->add(ModeAction());
            lActions->get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(KEY_LEFT_CTRL, ActionType.KB));
            lActions->get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(KEY_LEFT_ALT, ActionType.KB));
            //mode 4
            lActions->add(ModeAction());
            lActions->get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(KEY_W, ActionType.KB));

            //actions for middle switch
            //mode 1
            mActions->add(ModeAction());
            mActions->get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(MouseButtons.MIDDLE, ActionType.MOU));

            //actions for right switch
            //mode 1
            rActions->add(ModeAction());
            rActions->get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(MouseButtons.RIGHT, ActionType.MOU));

        }


        void cycleModeL() {
            this->modeL++;
            if(this->modeL >= lActions->size()) {
                this->modeL = 1;
            }
        }

        void cycleModeM() {
            this->modeM++;
            if(this->modeM >= mActions->size()) {
                this->modeM = 1;
            }
        }

        void cycleModeR() {
            this->modeR++;
            if(this->modeR >= rActions->size()) {
                this->modeR = 1;
            }
        }

    private:

        //void doDownActions(ModeAction modeActions, uint8_t mode) {
            //for (int i = 0; i < modeActions.at(mode).keys.length(); i++) {
                //if (modeActions[mode][i].keys[i].actionType == ActionType.KB) {
                    //Keyboard.press(modeActions[mode].keys[i].keyCode)
                //} else if (modeActions[mode].keys[i].actionType == ActionType.MOU) {
                    //mouseButtonPress(modeActions[mode].keys[i].keyCode);
                //}
            //}
            //sendMouseState();
        //}
//
        //void doUpActions(ModeAction modeActions, uint8_t mode) {
            //for (int i = 0; i < modeActions[mode].keys.length(); i++) {
                //if (modeActions[mode][i].keys[i].actionType == ActionType.KB) {
                    //Keyboard.release(modeActions[mode].keys[i].keyCode)
                //} else if (modeActions[mode].keys[i].actionType == ActionType.MOU) {
                    //mouseButtonRelease(modeActions[mode].keys[i].keyCode);
                //}
            //}
            //sendMouseState();
        //}

    public:

        //void leftDown() {
            //if (lActing == false) {
                //lActing = true;
                //doDownActions(lActions, modeL);
            //}
        //}
//
        //void middleDown() {
            //if (mActing == false) {
                //mActing = true;
                //doDownActions(mActions, modeM);
            //}
        //}
//
        //void rightDown() {
            //if (rActing == false) {
                //rActing = true;
                //doDownActions(rActions, modeR);
            //}
        //}
//
        //void leftUp() {
            //if (lActing == true) {
                //lActing = false;
                //doUpActions(lActions, modeL);
            //}
        //}
//
        //void middleUp() {
            //if (mActing == true) {
                //mActing = false;
                //doUpActions(mActions, modeM);
            //}
        //}
//
        //void rightUp() {
            //if (rActing == true) {
                //rActing = false;
                //doUpActions(rActions, modeR);
            //}
        //}

};

ActionManager actionManager = ActionManager();

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);

    pinMode(PinLED, OUTPUT);

    //pinMode(PinRight, INPUT_PULLUP); // sets the digital pin as output
    //attachInterrupt(PinRight, isrChangeR, CHANGE); // interrrupt is data ready
//
    //pinMode(PinMiddle, INPUT_PULLUP); // sets the digital pin as output
    //attachInterrupt(PinMiddle, isrChangeM, CHANGE); // interrrupt is data ready
//
    //pinMode(PinLeft, INPUT_PULLUP); // sets the digital pin as output
    //attachInterrupt(PinLeft, isrChangeL, CHANGE); // interrrupt is data ready

}

void loop() {

    //if (Serial.available()) {
////change mode
        //mode = Serial.parseInt();
//
////release all buttons
        //Keyboard.releaseAll();
        //Mouse.set_buttons(0, 0, 0);
//
////turn off LED
        //digitalWrite(PinLED, LOW);
//
////flush the serial input buffer
        //while (Serial.available()) {
            //Serial.read();
        //}
//
    //}
    //delay(1000);
    //Serial.println("Running");
}

//void isrChangeL() {
    //cli();
    //if (digitalRead(PinLeft) == LOW && nextPressLeft < millis()) {
////Serial.println("Pressed");
        //digitalWrite(PinLED, HIGH); //set the LED on
//
        //if (mode == 0) {
            //Mouse.set_buttons(1, 0, 0);
        //} else if (mode == 1) {
            //Keyboard.press(KEY_F11);
        //} else if (mode == 2) {
            //Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
            //Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ALT);
        //} else if (mode == 3) {
            //Keyboard.press(KEY_W);
        //}
//
        //nextPressLeft = millis() + timeBetween;
//
    //} else {
//// Serial.println("Released");
        //digitalWrite(PinLED, LOW); // set the LED off
//
        //if (mode == 0) {
            //Mouse.set_buttons(0, 0, 0);
        //} else if (mode == 1) {
            //Keyboard.release(KEY_F11);
        //} else if (mode == 2) {
            //Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
            //Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_ALT);
        //} else if (mode == 3) {
            //Keyboard.release(KEY_W);
        //}
//
        //nextPressLeft = millis() + timeBetween * 0.6;
//
//
    //}
    //sei();
//}
//
//void isrChangeM() {
    //cli();
////if (digitalRead(PinMiddle) == LOW && nextPressCenter < millis())
////{
////Keyboard.press(KEY_SPACE);
////delay(250);
////Keyboard.release(KEY_SPACE);
////}
//
    //if (digitalRead(PinMiddle) == LOW && nextPressCenter < millis()) {
////Serial.println("Pressed");
        //digitalWrite(PinLED, HIGH); //set the LED on
////Mouse.set_buttons(0, 1, 0);
//
        //nextPressCenter = millis() + timeBetween;
//
    //} else {
//// Serial.println("Released");
        //digitalWrite(PinLED, LOW); // set the LED off
////Mouse.set_buttons(0, 0, 0);
//
        //nextPressCenter = millis() + timeBetween * 0.6;
//
//
    //}
//
    //sei();
//}
//
//void isrChangeR() {
    //cli();
    //if (digitalRead(PinRight) == LOW && nextPressRight < millis()) {
////Serial.println("Pressed");
        //digitalWrite(PinLED, HIGH); // set the LED on
        //Mouse.set_buttons(0, 0, 1);
////Keyboard.press(KEY_F11);
        //nextPressRight = millis() + timeBetween;
    //} else {
//// Serial.println("Released");
        //digitalWrite(PinLED, LOW); // set the LED off
        //Mouse.set_buttons(0, 0, 0);
////Keyboard.release(KEY_F11);
        //nextPressRight = millis() + timeBetween * 0.6;
    //}
    //sei();
//}
```

compiler log:

```
Compiling debug version of 'click_switch_5_cycling' for 'Teensy LC'
click_switch_5_cycling.ino: In constructor ActionManager::ActionManager()

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 106:53: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 106:66: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 106:83: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 109:53: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 109:73: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 112:53: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 112:79: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 113:53: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 113:78: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 116:53: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 116:71: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 121:53: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 121:66: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 121:85: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 126:53: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 126:66: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino: 126:84: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

click_switch_5_cycling.ino:1: In file included from
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of bool LinkedList<T>::add(T) [with T = Action]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:83: required from here

LinkedList.h: 192:37: error: use of deleted function 'ListNode<Action>::ListNode()
ListNode<T> *tmp = new ListNode<T>()
LinkedList.h:19: note  ListNode<Action>  ListNode() is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed
struct ListNode

LinkedList.h: 19:8: error: no matching function for call to 'Action::Action()
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note  candidate  Action  Action(uint16_t, ActionType)
this->actionType = actionType
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note    candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(const Action&)
uint16_t keyCode
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(Action&&)
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

click_switch_5_cycling.ino:1: In file included from
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of ListNode<T>* LinkedList<T>::getNode(int) [with T = ModeAction]
LinkedList.h:314: required from T LinkedList<T>  get(int) [with T = ModeAction]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:106: required from here
LinkedList.h: 160:9: warning: converting 'false' to pointer type 'ListNode<ModeAction>*' [-Wconversion-null]
return false
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of bool LinkedList<T>::add(int, T) [with T = Action]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:262: required from here

LinkedList.h: 177:37: error: use of deleted function 'ListNode<Action>::ListNode()
ListNode<T> *tmp = new ListNode<T>()
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of bool LinkedList<T>::unshift(T) [with T = Action]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:262: required from here

LinkedList.h: 218:37: error: use of deleted function 'ListNode<Action>::ListNode()
ListNode<T> *tmp = new ListNode<T>()
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of T LinkedList<T>::remove(int) [with T = Action]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:262: required from here

LinkedList.h: 290:12: error: no matching function for call to 'Action::Action()
return T()
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note  candidate  Action  Action(uint16_t, ActionType)
this->actionType = actionType
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note    candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(const Action&)
uint16_t keyCode
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(Action&&)
Error compiling project sources
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Debug build failed for project 'click_switch_5_cycling'

click_switch_5_cycling.ino:1: In file included from
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of T LinkedList<T>::pop() [with T = Action]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:262: required from here

LinkedList.h: 242:12: error: no matching function for call to 'Action::Action()
return T()
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note  candidate  Action  Action(uint16_t, ActionType)
this->actionType = actionType
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note    candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(const Action&)
uint16_t keyCode
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(Action&&)
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

click_switch_5_cycling.ino:1: In file included from
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of T LinkedList<T>::shift() [with T = Action]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:262: required from here

LinkedList.h: 268:12: error: no matching function for call to 'Action::Action()
return T()
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note  candidate  Action  Action(uint16_t, ActionType)
this->actionType = actionType
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note    candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(const Action&)
uint16_t keyCode
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(Action&&)
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

click_switch_5_cycling.ino:1: In file included from
LinkedList.h: In instantiation of T LinkedList<T>::get(int) [with T = Action]
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:262: required from here

LinkedList.h: 316:14: error: no matching function for call to 'Action::Action()
T())
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note  candidate  Action  Action(uint16_t, ActionType)
this->actionType = actionType
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:70: note    candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(const Action&)
uint16_t keyCode
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note  candidate  constexpr Action  Action(Action&&)
click_switch_5_cycling.ino:65: note    candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Thanks for any help you can give me about what these errors are and how to fix them.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have been programming in Java recently, because many of your errors have a Java ‘whiff’ to them. This, as you’ve tagged, is C++, not Java.

1. `sendMouseState`:

   a. You wrote `leftPressed == true`. This is much more simply expressed by the expression `leftPressed`.

   b. You wrote `middlePressed == false`. This is much more simply expressed using the “not” operator `!`, as in `!middlePressed`.

   c. The code tests all eight possible combinations of `leftPressed`, `middlePressed` and `rightPressed`, calling `Mouse.set_buttons(#,#,#);`

   However, `bool`s evaluate to numbers: `false` evaluates to `0`, while `true` evaluates to `1`. All eight tests, and therefore the entire function, can therefore be boiled down to the single line:

   `Mouse.set_buttons(leftPressed, middlePressed, rightPressed);`
2. You declared to the compiler, in a few places, “There’s going to be a function called (e.g) `void mouseButtonPress(MouseButtons theButton);`”

   That’s fair enough - but the compiler only needs that if you’re going to *call* the function before you *define* it. Since you follow the declarations *immediately* by the definitions, the declarations are unnecessary: get rid of them.
3. Use of `enum`s:

   Declaring an `enum` lets you use symbols instead of raw numbers: well done! However, that’s *all* you need to use: the `enum`’s symbol: `LEFT`, `MIDDLE` or `RIGHT` is all you need.

   If you do feel the need to express the `enum`’s name, you need to use the `::` operator, not the `.` operator: `MouseButtons::LEFT`.
4. Use of `new`:

   You do not need to call `new` to create members of classes. Well, OK, you might if they’re declared as pointers (which you have done), but that’s your problem: you should declare them as simple members, not pointer members.

   For example, instead of:

   ```
   LinkedList<Action> *keys = new LinkedList<Action>();
   ```

   you simply need:

   ```
   LinkedList<Action> keys;
   ```

   Note that no `new` is needed now. Then, everywhere that you dereference the member with `keys->add(action);`, you use `keys.add(action);` instead.
5. Use of `this->`:

   You use `this->` a lot. You practically never have to: however, the one time you did need to was in the code:

   ```
   Action (uint16_t keyCode, ActionType actionType) {
       this->keyCode = keyCode;
       this->actionType = actionType;
   }
   ```

   Here, `this->` was needed to distinguish the class members from the passed-in parameters that have the same name. However, if you’d written the constructor correctly, using initialisation instead of assignment, you wouldn’t have needed `this->` here either:

   ```
   Action (uint16_t keyCode, ActionType actionType) :
       keyCode(keyCode),
       actionType(actionType) {
   }
   ```
6. `add()` followed by `get()`:

   You use the following code:

   ```
   lActions.add(ModeAction());
   lActions.get(lActions->size() - 1).addAction(Action(LEFT,MOU));
   ```

   That is, you add an empty `ModeAction`, then fetch it back with `get(...)` before manipulating it. Don’t.

   Instead, create a temporary `ModeAction` object, get it ready, *then* `add()` it to the list:

   ```
   ModeAction lMode1;
   lMode1.addAction(Action(LEFT,MOU));
   lActions.add(lMode1);
   ```

Comment: 1a and 1b are bad practice in Java too, 1c and 6 are bad algorithm (n Java too)

Comment: Dart, actually - been trying to learn it. Thanks for your detailed response.

1. a,b. I'm working with other people who aren't really programmers so I wanted to keep it explicit.
1. c. That's a good point, thanks.
2. I did that because I was getting the error: "variable or field 'mouseButtonPress' declared void" and I read that that was how to fix it. Something about the way Arduino handles function definitions.
3. I want the code to be explicit, so I'll change those to :: .

Comment: 4. I was using example code given by the LinkedList library (https://github.com/ivanseidel/LinkedList).
5. Ok.
6. Ok, I changed those.

I think I made all the changes you suggested, but it still won't compile. Here's the new code https://gist.github.com/dude8604/98f7d8e7e6f4d74349b1b974e8ea0d17 and compiler log https://gist.github.com/dude8604/e9685c4b49b6c90922ad09a69b5e4c34

It seems like most of the errors point to the LinkedList library. Are the remaining errors with the library or my code? Thanks.

Comment: @dude8604 4. That example `LinkedList` code is... abbreviated. It starts simply enough with a normal variable, then talks about creating one with `new`. It wasn't implying that was how it had to be done... It's also got a bug in it: I'll send a Pull request to the author. Edit: No need - it's already there, just not actioned. Sigh!

Comment: @dude8604  Since you want to create a linked list of `Action`s, in your `Action` class you need to have a "default" constructor: one which takes zero parameters. If you add the line
"`Action () : keyCode(0), actionType(KB) {}`"
to the class, `LinkedList<Action>` will now compile.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is giving you a clue that the problem is around line 106. You have there:

```
  LinkedList<ModeAction> *lActions = new LinkedList<ModeAction>();
  LinkedList<ModeAction> *mActions=new LinkedList<ModeAction>();
  LinkedList<ModeAction> *rActions=new LinkedList<ModeAction>();
```

You can't do procedural code (like `new`) in a data declaration. Also, I doubt that there is a function to be called so I would get rid of the brackets. Initializing member fields should be done in the constructor, not in the declaration.

Comment: I moved the assignment part into the constructor but I'm still getting similar errors. Should I edit my code and compiler log in the original post?

Comment: should not be a problem with C++11 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members

Comment: This isn't a forum, so to-ing and fro-ing with changes to the original post makes the question a moving target, and then the answers look meaningless. Hopefully John Burger's rather comprehensive answer will help you without you having to do that.

Comment: Juraj is right however that declaring pointers like that is OK under C++11. However as John Burger points out, it is easier not to use pointers in the first place. For one thing, if you are going to use `new` then you should use `delete` in the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

you use wrong syntax to access an enum member. use `::` not `.`

`Action(MouseButtons::LEFT, ActionType::MOU)`

EDIT:

second error is that LinkedList requires constructor without parameters on the template type

add constructor without parameters to class Action

Comment: Re: second error, Is there another Arduino vector library that wouldn't require that?

Comment: I tried it and now the program freezes.

Comment: why do you want to use dynamic vector? use array